# plqsl replicating vlookup

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

My query returns the following table:

```
|  CODE  |    DATE    |  VALUE  |
|  123   | 30/06/2012 |   11    |
|  231   | 01/07/2012 |   22    |
|  321   | 02/07/2012 |   11    |
|  234   | 03/07/2012 |   11    |
```

I need it to create a column based off of the DATE and VALUE column.  So it must take todays value ad divide it by the previous days

So once the query runs the result should be:

```
|  CODE  |    DATE    |  VALUE  |  RET  |
|  123   | 30/06/2012 |   11    |       |
|  231   | 01/07/2012 |   22    |  2.0  |
|  321   | 02/07/2012 |   11    |  0.5  |
|  234   | 03/07/2012 |   11    |  0.0  |
```

This is as far as I have got:

```
SELECT
    CODE
    DATE
    VALUE 
    (DATE/(TO_DATE(DATE)-1)) AS RET
FROM
    ....
```

But obviously you can't divide a date by another date and expect to get a number.

Thanks

Comment: So you want to divide by date and come to the conclusion that that is a silly thing to do. How can we help?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Rene I really appreciate the help.  I need the query to look at the date in the DATE column and then take the VALUE from that row and divide it by the value from the previous days date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to access previous value of a column you can use [lag](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm#i1327527) analytical function:

```
   -- sample of data from your question
   SQL> with t1(CODE, DATE1, VALUE1) as(
      2    select 123, to_date('30/06/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 11  from dual union all
      3    select 231, to_date('01/07/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 22  from dual union all
      4    select 321, to_date('02/07/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 11  from dual union all
      5    select 234, to_date('03/07/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 11  from dual
      6  )-- the query
      7  select code
      8       , Date1
      9       , Value1
     10       , to_char(value1 / lag(value1, 1) over(order by date1), '999990.0') ret
     11    from t1
     12  ;
```

Result:

```
      CODE DATE1           VALUE1      RET
---------- -----------   ----------   ---------
       123 30/06/2012         11 
       231 01/07/2012         22       2.0
       321 02/07/2012         11       0.5
       234 03/07/2012         11       1.0
```

Comment: Ahhh, Thanks Nicholas.  I wasn't aware of the lag function (very new to SQL)  thanks that does it!